# Reduce the asymptotic variance for a class of Metropolis-Hasting estimates

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, markov-chains

I'm running the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with state space $E$, target distribution $\mu=p\lambda$ and proposal kernel $Q$ to estimate $\mu(hf)$ for a fixed function $f:E\to[0,\infty)^3$ and a finite number of bounded $h:E\to[0,\infty)$. $p$ and the proposal kernel $Q$ both depend on a parameter which I want to choose such that the asymptotic variance of the estimates is reduced as much as possible or even minimized.

> How should I tackle this problem? Which estimator $A_ng$ for $\mu g$ should I use?

Let $\sigma^2(g):=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\operatorname{Var}[A_ng]$. Once I've fixed an estimator, I'm willing to assume that $\sigma^2(|f|)<\infty$ ($|\;\cdot\;|$ denoting the Euclidean norm). This should yield that $\sigma^2(hf_i)<\infty$ for all bounded $h:E\to[0,\infty)$ and $i=1,2,3$ and hence that a CLT holds for all estimates of interest.

I know several stronger conditions ensuring that a CLT holds for a broad class of functions; see, for example, section 5.2 in [General state space Markov chains and MCMC algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404033) by Gareth O. Roberts and Jeffrey S. Rosenthal. Moreover, a useful criterion on asymptotic variance reduction is given in Theorem 4 of [A note on Metropolis-Hastings kernels for general state spaces](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1027961031) by Luke Tierney.

However, these approaches leave me with the problem of minimizing the supremum of an integral functional. For example, if we use the ordinary ergodic average $A_ng:=\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}g(X_i)$, $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ being the Metropolis-Hastings chain, then Theorem 25 in the paper of Roberts and Rosenthal yields that we could try to minimize $$\sup_{g\in L^2(\mu)\setminus\{0\}}\frac{\left\|\kappa g\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}}{\left\|g\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}}\tag1.$$ The supremum occuring in $(1)$ makes it hard to choose the parameter minimizing this expression.

Since minimizing $(1)$ would yield way more than I need (it would yield minimum worst-case asymptotic variance for all $g\in L^2(\mu)$, but I'm only interested in estimates for $hf_i$), I hope that there is a better approach.

> So, what I would need is to find some nice expression for the worst-case asymptotic variance of $A_n(hf_i)$, for all bounded $h:E\to[0,\infty)$ and $i=1,2,3$. Maybe a nice upper bound only involving $f$.